# Repeating values when we use append function in list or update in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

when I try to append a Dictonary values to a list I'm getting the value appended multiple time but when I try to see what is really happening in there by using print statement, the values are iterating properly but while appending it is appending same value multiple times

Here is my code

```
from random import randint
x = {'1': 
        {
            'item_id': 6,
            'item_name': 'burger',
            'item_price': 10,
            'item_quantity': 2
        }, 
    '2': 
        {
            'item_id': 7,
            'item_name': 'pizza',
            'item_price': 15,
            'item_quantity': 4
        },
     '3':
        {
            'item_id': 8,
            'item_name': 'Biryani',
            'item_price': 20,
            'item_quantity': 6
            
        }
    }
cart=[]
items = {}
for y in x.values():
    items['name'] = y['item_name']
    items['price'] = y['item_price']
    items['quantity'] = y['item_quantity']
    print(items)
    cart.append(items)
print(cart)
```

And This is the Output:

```
{'name': 'burger', 'price': 10, 'quantity': 2}
{'name': 'pizza', 'price': 15, 'quantity': 4}
{'name': 'Biryani', 'price': 20, 'quantity': 6}
[{'name': 'Biryani', 'price': 20, 'quantity': 6}, {'name': 'Biryani', 'price': 20, 'quantity': 6}, {'name': 'Biryani', 'price': 20, 'quantity': 6}]
>
```

Comment: move items = {} inside your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating and appending the same dict `items` to `cart` again and again. Instantiate a new dict `items = {}` in each iteration of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

try initializing your dictionary every time inside the loop

```
cart=[]
for y in x.values():
    items = {}
    items['name'] = y['item_name']
    items['price'] = y['item_price']
    items['quantity'] = y['item_quantity']
    print(items)
    cart.append(items)
print(cart)
```